# How my server can get notified when someone sent an email to my mail ex:- (support@mydomain.com)

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I would like to build something like ticket management system (ex:- Zendesk, Freshdesk). So if someone sent a mail to my mailId **support@mydomain.com** my server should get notified regarding the mail details like (subject,text etc..)

One solution I have found for this is using **IMAP** as described [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) and I have setup a simple nodejs project

```
var imap = new Imap({
  user: '*****',
  password: '****',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true
});

imap.once('ready', () => {
imap.on('mail',(number)=>{
console.log('Got new emails',number);
})
})
```

But this code only giving me the number of new mails I have received. But not any details regarding the mail.

Is there any better approach for this problem ?

I would be thankfull if you could give me a little help

Comment: Why not setting a forwarding rule?

Comment: Hi Jescanellas, I have went through the doc (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en) for forwading emails. As described in the doc it will forward emails to another mail account right ? But I want my server to receive the mail. Please correct me if I am wrong and thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Set up an SMTP server to forward to it..  Run a rule/filter on reception. The whole SMTP infrastructure is entirely built around `push`ing emails around, and in many cases will work better than trying to `pull` via IMAP.